# Ant design 4.20 new Menu item style

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

Ant Design deprecated `<Menu.Item>` in 4.20.0, so I am converting it to a new format.

When I have the following code, how do I convert it into the new format?

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.Item key="1" className={css.first} onClick={onFirst}>item 1</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="2" className={css.second} onClick={onSecond}>item 2</Menu.Item>
</Menu>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant Design `v4.21.7` you can convert it like that

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Menu } from 'antd';

const App = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState();

  const onFirst = (e) => {
    console.log('click 1', e);
    setCurrent(e.key);
  };

  const onSecond = (e) => {
    console.log('click 2', e);
    setCurrent(e.key);
  };

  const items = [
    {
      label: 'Navigation One',
      children: [
        {
          label: 'item 1',
          onClick: onFirst,
          key: '1',
          className: 'first',
        },
        {
          label: 'item 2',
          onClick: onSecond,
          key: '2',
          className: 'second',
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  return <Menu selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal" items={items} />;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. what about the `className`? Are we allowed to use onClick in items? I couldn't find a doc for it.

Comment: onClick is not in the document but you can see it's working as expected [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1aobpr?file=demo.js).

Comment: it's working bcz `antd` are also using  [rc-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-menu)

Comment: @Pytan `className` also working pls check. i add class it's reflected in dom you can see it [here](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/ST_2.png) and updated ans and demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1aobpr?file=demo.js,index.css).

Comment: Hi, @Trace What do you mean?

Comment: No respect for backward compatibility. Just break whatever was in the past for adding few value.